# tcolorbox: lines after break?

Tags: tcolorbox

Is there something equivalent to "lines before break" for the end part in tcolorbox? If there is I can't find it ;-)

The following box should have at least 3 lines on the second page. As the code is created automatically any solution that involves manual break points (like `break at`) is not suitable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=lightgray!20!white,frame hidden,breakable]
a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean a bottom line for the first part of the box and a top line for the second part of the box? If yes, I also looked unsuccessfully for that. I planned to write a feature request to Thomas Sturm for that.

Comment: No I don't mean rules but text lines. I don't want a lonely last line on a page.

Comment: Ok, a slight misunderstanding ;-)

Answer (score 8):

There is a (very limited) support for that by using the `enlargepage flexible` option from version `3.12 (2014/07/29)`. This allows to enlarge the pre-last (becoming last) page to avoid such lonely lines. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,lipsum}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,colback=lightgray!20!white,frame hidden,breakable,
  enlargepage flexible=\baselineskip
  ]
a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Here, you avoid a single lonely line. If you insert some more lines, 2 lines will flip to the next page.

To avoid 2 lonely lines, you could use `enlargepage flexible=2\baselineskip`. Naturally, the enlarged page will become **too** large if you continue with that to higher values.

Note that this will not protect from getting a lonely line from one paragraph which is in the mid of other paragraphs. But at least, the worst case (a framed single line at the end) can be avoided...

Comment: Sounds like a Echternacher Springprozession: Two step forward, one step back ;-). enlargepage flexible=\baselineskip is ok in this case but a `minimum height of split=` option would be imho useful too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm a little bit reluctant in changing the sensible breaking algorithm, but I will put your suggestion on my TODO list and I will see if it can be implemented without harm to other things.

Comment: I found the solution: `before upper={\widowpenalties=3 10000 10000 150}`. This naturally won't work if the last line is a paragraph on its own but then I can use `\par\nobreak`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah... eTeX goodies :-) Yes, that's much better than manually influencing the split points.